# TypeScript: какие достоинства и недостатки есть у опции "strict": true?

Tags: vue.js, typescript

При использовании TypeScript, [официальная документация Vue.js](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html) рекомендует установить опцию `"strict": true` в **tsconfig.json**. Мой проект - не SPA, потому Vue.js используется выборочно; на каких-то страницах используется и jQuery. Когда я установил опцию `"strict": true`, у меня появилось столько ошибок в прежде рабочем коде, что я его примерно час исправлял, а когда понял, что это займёт ещё несколько часов, откатил изменения и убрал эту опцию. Честно говоря, рекомендация `"strict": true` не соответствует заявлению из документации Vue.js:

> Постепенно внедряемая экосистема, которая масштабируется из библиотеки
>   в полнофункциональный фреймворк.

С одной стороны `"strict": true` - вроде бы штука хорошая: меньше багов в продакшен-коде. С другой стороны, если внезапно включить эту функцию, всё приложение рассыпется и нужно делать кучу исправлений.

Холивар о том, стоит ли использовать `"strict": true`, можно вести до бесконечности и это вызовет негативную реакцию администраторов; я же прошу просто поделиться Вашим опытом, рассказать, какие достоинства и недостатки есть у данной опции, к каким последствиям может привести её внедрение и т. д., а я и другие читатели этого вопроса уже сами решат, имеет ли смысл ломать прежде написанный код включением этой опции или нет.

P. S. Убедительная просьба: если Вы минусуете вопрос или ответы на него, то в комментариях укажите причину. Тогда, вопрос или ответ на него можно будет улучшить.